# Typescript : check a string for number

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm new to web development, and in my function want to check if a given string value is a number. In case the string isn't a valid number I want to return null.

The following works for all cases except when the string is "0" in which case it returns null.

```
parseInt(columnSortSettings[0]) || null;
```

How do I prevent this from happening. Apparantly parseInt doesn't consider 0 as an integer!

Comment: `0` is a falsy value ..

Comment: I haven't posted [this link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/182416/A-Collection-of-JavaScript-Gotchas) in a while, but it's always worth a read for anyone learning/using javascript

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since `0` is act as false , so you can use **[`isNaN()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN)** in this case

```
var res = parseInt(columnSortSettings[0], 10);
return isNaN(res) ? null : res;
```

Comment: Don't forget the `radix`.

Answer (score 4):

It's because you are basically testing 0 which is also false.
You can do

```
var n = columnSortSettings[0];
if(parseInt(n, 10) || n === '0'){
    //...
}
```

You can also test instead if it's a number

```
if(typeof(parseInt(n, 10)) === 'number'){
  //...
}
```

But beware cause

```
typeof Infinity === 'number';
typeof NaN === 'number';
```

Comment: Don't forget the `radix`.

Comment: @Andy, yup totally forgot :)

Comment: Thanks @Eric . As SO lets me accept only one answer, I've upvoted your answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the **isNumeric** operator from *rxjs* library (importing rxjs/util/isNumeric